# Performing a SHACL valdiation on a GraphDB repository using RDF4J

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

We are trying to run a full SHACL valdiation on a GraphDB 9.1 (free version) repository (as part of a comparative analysis). For this we try to use RDF4J (3.0.3) as mentioned in the beginning of the documentation:

http://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/shacl-validation.html linking to https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/shacl/

Our problem is that as of current we haven't found out, how to generate a ShaclSail for an existing GraphDB repository. The documentation for GraphDB in RDF4J (http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/using-graphdb-with-the-rdf4j-api.html) focusses on accessing, creating and modifying repositories, while ShaclSail needs a MemoryStore. Working with a local NativeStore like it's possible with RDF4Js own repositories was unsuccessful as well.

Is there currently a way to (somewhat natively) perform a full SHACL validation on a GraphDB repository using RDF4J? I didn't include code samples because most stuff we tried is similarish to the docs or consists of primarily trivial extensions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As its written in the GraphDB documentation: "A repository with SHACL validation must be created from scratch, i.e., Create new."

One of the options is to export the old storage, create the new repository with Shacl validation enabled, following the guide into GraphDB documentation.

Here is a link to Shacl validation guide:
http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/shacl-validation.html